# I access past data by parameter in a Moodle mForm?

Tags: php, moodle

I need to get the value of a parameter of a "mForm" moodle form and do not know how.

I should add the static field "Date Created" to the editing section of a course and not show it as Unix timestamp.

To this had the following:

```
$fecha_creacion = date('m/d/Y', xxxxxxxxx);

$mform->addElement('static', 'desc' , 'Fecha de Creación');

$mform->setDefault('desc', $fecha_creacion);
```

where he "xxxxxxxxx" is the integer value obtained from BD in the "mdl_couse" table ('timecreated').

Therefore I need to get the integer value, which is the same parameter that is passed in:

```
$mform->addElement('static', 'timecreated' , 'Fecha de Creación');
```

I'm new to moodle. 
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:**

```
    $customdata = array('timecreated' => $course->timecreated);
    $fecha_c = $customdata['timecreated'];
```

or

```
    $fecha_c = $course->timecreated;
```

to get value timecreated

```
    $fecha_creacion = date('d/m/Y',$fecha_creacion);
    $mform->addElement('static', 'desc' , 'Fecha de Creación');
    $mform->setDefault('desc', $fecha_creacion);
```

Only in the edition of course:(not for create course)

```
    if (!empty($course->id)) {
        $fecha_c = $course->timecreated;
        $fecha_creacion = date('d/m/Y',$fecha_creacion);
        $mform->addElement('static', 'desc' , 'Fecha de Creación');
        $mform->setDefault('desc', $fecha_creacion);
    }
```

*Thanks for you help!!*

Answer (score 1):

Moodle uses HTML_QuickForm so you should be able to consult the documentation at http://pear.php.net/package/HTML_QuickForm/docs/latest/.

If I understand correctly, in this case you need something along the lines of:

```
$mform->getElementValue('timecreated');
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: thank you very much for the reply, unfortunately it was not me, but I will investigate QuikForm, hope to get results.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a parameter to the form

In your edit.php file

```
// Get the course record that you want.
$course = $DB->get_record('course', array('id' => $id));

// Pass the time created value in an array.
$customdata = array('timecreated' => $course->timecreated);
$form = new edit_form(null, $customdata);
```

Then in your edit_form.php file

```
class edit_form extends moodleform {

    public function definition() {

        $mform =& $this->_form;

        // Copy the timecreated value.
        $timecreated = $this->_customdata['timecreated'];
        // Pass timecreated as the 4th parameter - userdate() will display the date in the users locale.
        // You should also use get_string() to display the label in the users language.
        $mform->addElement('static', 'timecreated', get_string('timecreated', 'yourpluginname'), userdate($timecreated));
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply, I understand the logic, but has not yet given me the method result, I keep trying to see what I get.

Comment: what happens is that the page is loading, but nothing happens, as if carrying a heavy operation.